# Submitting two forms in Rails sharing a same param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form like that:

```
<%= form_for @report do |f| %>
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <h3 class="page-header">
        Children
      </h3>
      <div class="row">
        <% students.each do |student| %>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">

            <div class="std_container">
              <%= check_box_tag "student_ids[]", student.id, nil, {id: "check_#{student.id}", class: "student_check"} %>
              <%= label_tag "check_#{student.id}" do %>
                <div class="std_label"><%= student.name %></div>
                <div class="std_img thumbnail"><img src="http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" alt=""></div>
              <% end %>
            </div>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%= render "form_categories", f: f, report_notes: @report.report_notes %>
    <%= render "messages/form", ????? %>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

And I need to render these two partials on the bottom. The `'messages'` partial is a form that responds to a different controller but needs to use the `"student_ids[]"` parameter present on the `@report` form together with its own parameters. This partial is:

```
<%= form_for @message do |f| %>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
    <%= f.hidden_field :professor_id, :value => current_user.professor.id %>

    <%= f.label :text, "Texto" %>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>

    <%= f.submit "Enviar", class: "btn btn-default" %>
  </div>

</div>
<% end %>
```

How do build this "messages" partial in a way that I can use the "student_ids[]" and submit it to its controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. I solved this problem by using javascript.